# Varnish variables and DRY code

Tags: dry, varnish-vcl

As a python engineer one learns to write DRY style code; not because it's a buzzword, but it makes your code cleaner looking and readable to others.

Anyone who's endured reading a former colleague's code can understand that well.

With varnish, there's not variable assignment so how can one even attempt to write DRY style rules?

Consider the following:

I have a cluster of backend instances running apache with over ten `vhosts`.  There's a front end instance that needs to re-write based on the `vhost`.

I'm stuck with this:

```
if ( req.url ~ "^/amp/" ) {
    # vhost's AMP code == xyz
    if (req.http.host = "host1.com") {
       set req.url = regsub(req.url, "/amp/",  "/nps/$host1-brand-code/");
    }
     if (req.http.host = "host2.com") {
       set req.url = regsub(req.url, "/amp/",  "/nps/$host2-brand-code/");
    }
    ...
}
```

What's upsetting here is the repeat of `regsub`

```
"/nps/$host1-brand-code/"
```

What if the publishers decide to change that next month to `/new-nps-url/$host1-brand-code`.  I will be forced to update many if statements for just one cluster, and we have many clusters!

Comment: Have you looked into [varnish-modules](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules)? It appears they have `vmod-var` which may allow you to set a variable like you'd want. They have some [tests](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/tree/master/src/tests/var) for usage, and [test02.vtc](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/master/src/tests/var/test02.vtc) may be of particular interest to you.

Comment: @CoryShay that's a good solution, many thanks for the link!  I have to approach it carefully though, because varnish is installed/updated via chef on these clusters, and introducing a new `so` needs care.

Answer (score 1):

So one option if you don't want to go the route of VMODs (though the `var` vmod that @cory-shay suggested is a good one) is to use custom sub-routines and then use the HTTP variables to pass your parameters around like you would in Python.

In your case:

```
sub ourcompany_amp_code {
   set req.url = rebsub(req.url, "/amp/", "/nps/" + req.http.BRAND_CODE);
   // Cleanup so it does not get passed to upstream
   // Though the "_" in the name will generally prevent that
   // in any case
   unset req.http.BRAND_CODE;
}


sub vcl_recv {
     if (req.http.host = "host1.com") {
        set req.http.BRAND_CODE = "$host1-brand-code";
     } else if (req.http.host = "host2.com") {
        set req.http.BRAND_CODE = "$host2-brand-code";
     }
     call ourcompany_amp_code;
}
```

This would let you do multiple things with the brand code in theory. But if you were only going to do the single replacement you can just move the body of `ourcompany_amp_code` to be after your series of if statements.

Using the `var` vmod you can simply replace the use of the `req.http.BRAND_CODE` with `var.set`